# Where do you declare UITapGestureRecognizer() in relation to addGestureRecognizer() in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

### Problem

`centerLabelGesture` is being defined outside of the scope of `viewDidLoad()`, so at the time that `.addGestureRecognizer(centerLabelGesture)` is called, centerLabelGesture is not defined yet.

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var screen: UIView!
    var centerLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        screen = UIView()
        centerLabel = UILabel()

        view.addSubview(screen)
        screen.addSubview(centerLabel)

        screen.backgroundColor = .white
        screen.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(view)
            make.right.equalTo(view)
            make.left.equalTo(view)
            make.bottom.equalTo(view)
        }

        centerLabel.text = "I hope I'm centered."
        centerLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.center.equalTo(screen)
        }
        centerLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        centerLabel.addGestureRecognizer(centerLabelGesture)
    }

    let centerLabelGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(centerLabelTapped))

    @objc func centerLabelTapped() {
        centerLabel.text = "Ouch, you tapped me!"
    }

}
```

### Update 1/19/2019

matt pointed out that `centerLabelGesture` needs to be declared prior to `centerLabel.addGestureRecognizer(centerLabelGesture)`, inside `viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a subtle mistake. The problem is the place you've put this line:

```
let centerLabelGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(centerLabelTapped))
```

Move that line into the `viewDidLoad` code:

```
centerLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
let centerLabelGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(centerLabelTapped))
centerLabel.addGestureRecognizer(centerLabelGesture)
```

The reason is that where you've got that line, it's an instance property, and when you say `self` as the target in an instance property initializer, it doesn't mean what you think it does (it means the *class*, not the *instance*), so the message when you tap is misdirected and does nothing.

I have filed a bug on this issue; in my opinion the compiler should at least warn you that you're making a potential mistake.

Comment: Also to clarify for my notes, when you say

_"The reason is that where you've got that line, it's an instance property"_ 

What is it an instance property of?

Comment: Of ViewController. You might want to start reading my online Swift explanation: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch01.html#_object_members

Comment: Woah so cool! I just bought your O'Reilly iOS 11 book last week... :D Thanks Matt!

Comment: :) It works both ways. Questions on Stack Overflow (like yours) give me clues as to what sort of thing the books need to explain!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in viewDidLoad

```
centerLabelGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
```

Comment: Hmm, adding this inside `viewDidLoad` returns an error:
```Value of type 'UILabel' has no member 'numberOfTapsRequired'```